# Python: Adding Directory One Level Up to System Path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, sys

I already have a solution to this problem, but just want to make sure it's the optimal one and doing what I think it's doing. I have a folder structure like this:

```
Main
+ data
++ __init__.py
++ get_data.py
+ work
++ stuff.py
```

get_data.py has a class named GetData that I need to import. I'm in stuff.py. When I use:

```
from data.get_data import GetData
```

It does not work. So I did this:

```
sys.path.append(".")
```

If I do that, my code works. However, it looks a bit odd when I look at the paths via:

```
print(sys.path)
```

I get this:

```
['C:\\Main\\Notebooks', '.']
```

I think what I'm doing is taking the current working directory and appending that path one level higher. And this works. Is this correct? Is there a more optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add the following statement at the beginning of the file:

```
 import os,sys 
 sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

It adds the path of the module that needs to be imported to the system path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Add an empty `__init__.py` File In Your `data` And `work` Directory.

Main

- data 
  ++ `__init__.py`
  ++ get_data.py
- work
  ++ `__init__.py`
  ++ stuff.py

After That `from data.get_data import GetData` Will Work.

Comment: I did that, but forgot to post it on here. Thought it would work without __init__.py in Python 3.3+ though.